# Swift 3, want to perform timeout when using URLSession to load image from server

Tags: swift3, timeout, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, urlsession

I'm using swift 3. I want to add timeout to URLSession when doing download task. I did use configuration to change my setting, however, it doesn't work. The code didn't perform timeout... If the server didn't response quickly, it will fail.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIImageView {
    func loadImage(url: URL) -> URLSessionDownloadTask {

    let session: URLSession = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 70
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 70
        return URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()

    let downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: { [weak self] url, response, error in

        if error == nil, let url = url, let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let strongSelf = self {
                    strongSelf.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
    return downloadTask
}
}
```

Any comment is appreciated!!

Comment: var timeoutIntervalForResource: TimeInterval { get set }
Discussion
This property determines the resource timeout interval for all tasks within sessions based on this configuration. The resource timeout interval controls how long (in seconds) to wait for an entire resource to transfer before giving up. The resource timer starts when the request is initiated and counts until either the request completes or this timeout interval is reached, whichever comes first.
The default value is 7 days.

Comment: try commenting out  timeoutIntervalForResource. The default is 7 days and you are setting it to 70 seconds